# jquery $.post adding unwanted characters

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery's post method to communicate with php and log a user in. Here is the code:

```
    var user = $('#user').val();
    var pass = $('#password').val();
    $.post('php/login.php',
          {
              post_code:'login',
              username:user,
              password:pass
          },
          function(response){                
              alert(response);
              if(response== 'good'){
                changePage('homePage');
              }
              else{alert('bad info');}
     });
```

so with a succesful login, php echos `good` and when javascript alerts the response it would also alert `good`. By doing some debuggin I found out that php echos a string `good` with length of 4 but javascript somehow adds two empty spaces at the beggining of the string and makes it `__good`. My workaround this problem was:

```
              response= response.substr(response.length - 4);
```

but I still have that curiosity on why those 2 empty spaces were added to the response string

Comment: You probably have some spaces in your PHP file, before the `<?php` block.

Comment: You probably have some spaces in your PHP script, before or after PHP tags are the most common. `response.trim()` would solve it, but you should really find and remove the spaces in your PHP file. As a sidenote this is not secure **at all** !!

Comment: Are there extra space in the actual source that is output from PHP (not just what appears on screen)?

Comment: To the point about security raised earlier. You definitely should add some form of session-based login token here, as without it, any one could easily build a script to just fire away at your login endpoint to try to guess valid logins.

Comment: @adeneo this is just a testing website, it is not meant for public access. Also I double checked the php file and there are no white spaces before the <?php tag, and when i go to that file location in the browser and echo the response length it also says it contains 4 characters. So the problem is when jquery gets the response

Comment: If you can't find the source of the whitespace (and it's not jQuery), just trim it with either `response.trim()` or the more cross browser jQuery version `$.trim( responce )` ?

Answer (score 0):

If there are spaces before `<?php` in your php script they'll get prepended to your `"good"` answer string.